# U.S. citizen living in France w/ French work permit - is it illegal to keep working for U.S. company?

Tags: france, freelance

I have been browsing other similar questions, and I am hoping to find a more certain answer because I'm sure someone has had the same experience.

I am a U.S. citizen who moved to France 4 months ago for my husband's job. I hold a carte de sejour, which includes a work permit so I am legal to work here. But I have been continuing to work remotely for my company in the States, and now they are asking questions and I fear that is not legal?

Any input is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You used the “freelance” tag, what's your status? How much money/turnover are we talking about? If you are really doing freelance work (i.e. not an employee) and your yearly turnover is under €30k, you might look at the *autoentrepreneur* status, it's really quite easy.

Comment: Actually, "freelancer" is not accurate - I am a contract employee.

Answer (score 8):

First point is that if you work in France, you are supposed to be affiliated to French “social protection” system. That entails paying income-dependent mandatory contributions but also benefits (health insurance, retirement pension, unemployment insurance).

If the US company you're working for does not have any legal entity in France, you are in the case of a [firme étrangère](https://www.urssaf.fr/portail/firme-etrangere). The company should declare your status and pay their part of tax. That might require some efforts on their side to deal with the French authorities. The process is described (in French) in the linked page.

If the US company has a legal entity in France, that entity should be your employer.

Now, if you are not a permanent employee of the US company but a freelancer/contractor, it is your duty to setup a legal framework in France that allow you such freelancing. First point is still valid. There are several ways to setup such framework, the simplest one being [auto entrepreneur](https://www.economie.gouv.fr/cedef/micro-entrepreneur-auto-entrepreneur), but it depends on the annual turnover you get from this activity, and various other issues.