# Living in France for 9 months with German wife as a Freelancer/Consultant

Tags: france, eu, taxes

My wife is a dual German/US citizen and will be conducting research under a grant funded by the French government in Paris for 9 months. I hope to be able to join her, but would need to work while there in order to support us. I am a US citizen working as a full-time freelancer/consultant with US clients. My work is remote and so in theory is not difficult to take with me anywhere, but I understand that the implications of working in Europe may mean double taxation or perhaps breaking the law. My intention is to operate legally, but it is difficult to find the proper path in terms of visa application, residency status, and tax status to make that happen. Does anybody have experience with a situation similar to this or perhaps knowledge of the proper path to follow?

Comment: I should add that our intention is not to establish permanent residence. We would be staying for the duration of the her research project (up to 9 months and no more) and then returning to the US.

Comment: The question is nonetheless far better suited to expats than to travel.  You will need a carte de séjour and so on, as you are staying over 90 days.

Comment: Flagged for migration to Expats.

Comment: Ok, now that it's migrated, I re-read it, and I think it ought to be split into separate questions.  That's because you are asking about visa, residency, and self-employment; these are separate issues.  As a US citizen, you do not need a visa.  For residency, you will apply for a *carte de séjour de membre de la famille d un citoyen de l’union* (residence permit for the family member of an EU citizen).  For work, you'll probably want to (or have to) set up a legal entity to operate as a freelancer, but I'm fuzzy on those details.  The answer may already be here, however; have a look around.

Comment: Related: http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/7474/u-s-citizen-living-in-france-w-french-work-permit-is-it-illegal-to-keep-work/7475#7475

Answer (score 5):

As your wife is an EU citizen exercising treaty rights by working in another member state, you are entitled to an automatic  carte de séjour de membre de la famille d un citoyen de l’union - which you need apply for within 3 months of your arrival in France.

It does however, normally take them 6-12 months to issue this so is unlikely you will receive it before you leave. But you can work from the day you arrive as is is an EU right.