# Can my American wife work for the US while living in France?

Tags: usa, france, taxes

I'm French, my wife is American. We live in Paris. Can she work for the US on a remote job, and if yes what are the implications tax wise? I assume she'll have to pay US Federal taxes (not State, since she doesn't live in the US?) in addition to full French taxes?

Comment: Some clues here https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/7474/u-s-citizen-living-in-france-w-french-work-permit-is-it-illegal-to-keep-work/7475#7475

Comment: Worth mentioning that she **already** has to pay the US Federal taxes, by virtue of being a US citizen.

Comment: If she weren't a US citizen or green card holder, she wouldn't be subject to US taxes on that work income, since she's not working in the US. But since she's a US citizen, her worldwide income subject to US taxes. She can claim the Foreign Earned Income Exclusion and/or the Foreign Tax Credit to reduce her US taxes.

Comment: She might actually have to pay state taxes, depending on the state she was last resident and how long she's been away.